# What happened to the 737's cockpit skylights?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, windows

Older-model 737s had very distinctive set of upwards-facing windows above the main, forwards-facing cockpit windows; not unlike those you'd find on MD-80-series airliners and on 727s.

These windows appear to also be present on early-model NGs (or retrofitted classics; I have a hard time telling, and absent on later-model classics; specifically ones with high-bypass engines).

[image]

*(Photo likely by Maor X [on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Venezolana_Maiquetia.jpg))*

On later-model NGs and the MAX, however, these windows are gone:

[image]

*(Photo by Jpedreira [on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:20080309_MG_8707_TC-JGE.jpg))*

Why would these windows, which are arguably useful in giving pilots a better vertical field-of-view, be removed? Has their usefulness in finding nearby air traffic been superseded by TCAS and ADS-B? Even then, why remove the windows when they act as (an extremely reliable, albeit less-precise) redundant system?